# Finding $pdf$ of $V=X+Y$ where $X$~$unif(0,1)$ and $f_Y(y) =e^{−y}I_{(0,\infty)}(y)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

> Consider independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ has a
>   uniform $(0,1)$ distribution and $Y$ has $pdf$ $$f_Y(y)
>  =e^{−y}I_{(0,\infty)}(y)$$
>
> Give the pdf of $V=X+Y$.

I found a similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1861728/need-help-finding-joint-distribution-of-uniform-and-exponential?rq=1) but I would like to make sure I am applying it correctly to this problem.

In the case that $v \geq 1$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
F_{X+Y}(v) 
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{v-x} e^{-y}dydx \\\\
&= \int_0^1 -e^{-y} |_0^{v-x}dx \\\\
&= \int_0^1(-e^{-(v-x)}-(-e^0))dx \\\\
&= \int_0^1 (-e^{-v}e^x+1)dx \\\\
&= (-e^{-v}e^x+x) |_0^1 \\\\
&= (-e^{-v}e+1)-(-e^{-v}e^0+0) \\\\
&= -e^{-v+1}+e^{-v}+1 \\\\
\end{align*}$$

And so differentiating, I get that

$$f_{X+Y}(v)=e^{-v+1}-e^{-v}$$

In the case that $v\in(0,1)$ we have

$$\begin{align*}
F_{X+Y}(v) 
&= \int_0^v \int_0^{v-x} e^{-y}dydx \\\\
&= \int_0^v -e^{-y} |_0^{v-x}dx \\\\
&= \int_0^v(-e^{-(v-x)}-(-e^0))dx \\\\
&= \int_0^v (-e^{-v}e^x+1)dx \\\\
&= (-e^{-v}e^x+x) |_0^v \\\\
&= (-e^{-v}e^v+v)-(-e^{-v}e^0+0) \\\\
&= -1+v+e^{-v}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

And so differentiating, I get that

$$f_{X+Y}(v)=1-e^{-v}$$

So the $pdf$ would be a piecewise function looking like

$$ f_{X+Y}(v)=  
\begin{cases} 
1-e^{-v} & 0 \lt v \lt 1 \\
e^{-v+1}-e^{-v} & v \ge 1  
\end{cases} $$

Comment: Also, is there an integration calculator that I can use to check the integration in the case where the solution is in terms of a variable v?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: You mean to check if the result integrates to 1? Try wolframalpha.com

Comment: Oh, I suppose I could do that. I meant is there a way to check that, say, $\int_0^v \int_0^{v-x} e^{-y} dydx$ results in $-1+v+e^{-v}$. But I suppose checking that the density integrates to 1 would also verify that.

Comment: Wolfram can do that too, but it can be tricky to ask it in the right way. I just got it to work (and it's right btw).

Comment: I got that $\int_0^1 v(1-e^{-v})dv \neq 1$. Does that mean I made an error

Comment: Oh wait, should it be the sum of the two densities that equals 1, since it's piecewise?

Comment: @John H Yes of course.

Comment: I got that that is 1.5.

Comment: The function you suggest as PDF integrates to $1$ since $$\int_0^1(1-e^{-v})dv=(v+e^{-v})^1_0=1+e^{-1}-1=e^{-1}$$ and $$\int_1^\infty (e^{-v+1}-e^{-v})dv=(e^{-v}-e^{-v+1})^\infty_1=1-e^{-1}$$

Comment: Oh, I thought that you had to multiply by $v$ within each integral

Comment: No, actually your lecture notes should mention that $$\int_\mathbb Rf_V(v)dv=1$$ and $$\int_\mathbb Rvf_V(v)dv=E(V)$$

Comment: Oh you're right. Was going off memory. Thanks!

Comment: I have added an alternate proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate proof :

The pdf of the sum of two independant random variables is equal to the **convolution** of their pdfs, say $\varphi$ and $\psi$ under the form:

$$f_{X+Y}(v)= \int \varphi_X(v-y)\psi_Y(y)du=\int 1_{[0,1]}(v-y)1_{[0,+\infty)}e^{-y}dy=$$

$$= \int_{\max(v-1,0)}^v e^{-y}dy=[-e^{-y}]_{\max(v-1,0)}^v=e^{-\max(v-1,0)}-e^{-v}$$

whence your result.

Now, how can we check it ? One of the best ways to test a pdf is to use simulation.

Here is the result showing an excellent fit between theory (red curve) and experiment (histogram on one million samples):

[image]

Here is the Matlab program that has generated the figure (note that the standard exponential distribution is equivalent with $-\ln(U)$ where $U$ is a uniform variable on $[0,1]$):

> clear all;close all;hold on
>
> n=1000000;set(gcf,'color','w');
>
> S=rand(1,n)-log(rand(1,n));
>
> hist(S,100)
>
> u=0:01:1;v=1:0.01:7;
>
> M=145000;
>
> plot(u,M*(1-exp(-u)),'r')
>
> plot(v,M*(exp(-v+1)-exp(-v)),'r')